# How to submit (POST) the form to the jQuery Fancybox iFrame?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, form-submit

When submitting a form, it usually goes to refresh the current window. I am now trying to use jQuery Fancybox to maintain on the same page. This means something like the modal window, the original page with an overlay, and the popup dialogue shows the iframe content.

form code like this:

```
<form name="MyFormName" id="MyFormID" action="https://www.example.com/somepage" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="Student_Name" value="Peter">
<input type="hidden" name="Student_Sex" value="Male">
<input type="hidden" name="Student_Age" value="16">
<input src="button.png"  type="image">
</form>
```

The jQuery Fancybox I wrote like this:

```
        $("#MyFormID").submit(function() {
            $.fancybox.open({
                href : 'https://www.example.com/somepage',
                type : 'iframe',
                width: 1024,
                height: 768,
                padding : 5
            });
        });
```

Oops!! the Fancybox shows, but the values in the form do NOT pass to the Fancybox.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1) Open iframe passing all values as URL parameters, for example, `https://www.example.com/somepage?Student_Name=Peter&Student_Sex=Male`

2) Post your form to initially hidden iframed page and then display that iframe as (fancybox) inline content (e.g., not using `type : 'iframe'`, but use fancybox usually, as displaying any other html element)